# Is there a faster way to copy-paste dynamic ranges in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to merge daily report to a single main document. Before, I was using Excel functions to do this. But the file size became enormous. So after all I thought, I may use VBA to eliminate huge amount of functions on the worksheets and reduce file size and calculation time as well.

Basically I have main line numbers as database on Sheet1 (main document). From Sheet2 I need to take daily amounts of works done for the line numbers listed on Sheet1.

For example, in Sheet1, cell "M3" represents the first line number (Line-01). In cell "X3", there will be work amount (10 joints) which comes from Sheet2 Range "O:O".
This will repeat at random times according to daily performance. So I would have datas from range "O3" to "O1000" (even more).

```
Sub DailyProgress()
    Dim i As Long

    Sheets(1).Activate

    Range("X3:X" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(vlookup(M3,Sheet2!D:O,12,0),Text(,))"

    i = 3
    'Because my first cell is on row 3
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 12))        
        Cells(i, 24).Copy
        Cells(i, 24).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I wrote the code to make vlookup, copy and paste as value. But this block is not smooth enough. By the way, I need to copy datas to cells "Y3" and "Z3" from Sheet2. So It will take much more time next time.

Comment: Interesting formula.. what is the purpose of `TEXT(,)` may I ask?

Comment: Actually I saw this before on internet. I use it instead of quotation marks to make formula more clear. Like `=IF(A1=TEXT(,),TEXT(,),(B1*2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that instead of copy/paste you could just use `Cells(i, 24).Value = Cells(i, 24).Value` which should be quicker. Also if you don't do this for every cell but for a full range at once it would be a lot quicker: `Range("X3", "X" & LastRow).Value = Range("X3", "X" & LastRow).Value`

Since you already determined the `LastRow` for writing the formula, you could just use the same to transform it into a value (without a loop).

```
Sub DailyProgress()
    With Sheets(1).Range("X3:X" & .Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(vlookup(M3,Sheet2!D:O,12,0),Text(,))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```